# What is the null hypothesis in the definition of Sensitivity and Specificity?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, biostatistics, definition

I have hard time to understand that what is the null hypothesis in the definition of Sensitivity and Specificity [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity)? I'm student of Statistics and from my little knowledge in this field I can see that the here null hypothesis should be:

$\textrm{H}_{0}:\textrm{ Person is healthy}$

Is this true? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Sensitivity and specificity are not hypotheses themselves. They are indices, or statistics. The wikipedia page says that their 2X2 table-form definition resembles the definition of H0 and H1 probabilities (type I and II errors).

Comment: Thanks @ttnphns for your comment. I know **Sensitivity** and **Specificity** are not hypotheses. But they are related to hypotheses and I want to know that what would be the hypothesis in this case. I hope these lines will make clarification about my intention. Thanks

Comment: What is the hypothesis about the current temperature outdoors?  We estimate things all the time without having hypotheses.  Know what sensitivity and specificity *estimate* and whether that is relevant to your problem.  Hint: it seldom is because these two measures reverse the flow of time/information flow.

Comment: The Wiki-article describes sensitivity and specificity as two properties of any test, be it a medical or a statistical one. Do not mix them together.